# FIll in text fields in a UIWebView by element name

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

I'd like to write an iPhone app that packs the contents of a website into the app. First problem: entering the user data. I've tried the following:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.username.text.value='testUser'"];
```

I have verified that I can run javascript at that time, a simple alert() works. However, I did not have any succes filling in that text field. The text field does not have an ID assigned, just a name (username). I did not find examples on the internet with an object that does not have an ID, and because I'm not familiar with javascript at all, I need your help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only use DOM methods you probably need to do it like this, assuming it is the first form in the document and the input is named "username":

```
document.forms[0].username.value = "testUser"
```

Or if you add `id="username"` to the input element you can do:

```
document.getElementById("username").value = "testUser"
```

But also make sure to evaluate the script after the `UIWebView` has finished loading so that the DOM is completely loaded and ready for manipulation, i would recommend to use the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate method in the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Never seen the access to the DOM with forms[0] and it worked perfectly for me too! Thanks for the input.

Comment: Long since i wrote this answer... but yeah i works (part of [DOM level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html])) but i guess `getElementsByTagName("form")` is more canonical these days.

Comment: How about add image into textBox? any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('input[name="name"]').text('Hello');`

If you are not using jQuery, you can do:

```
var myInput = table.getElementsByTagName("input");   
for (var i = 0; i < myInput.length; i++) {   
    if(myInput[i].getAttribute("name")=="name") {
        myInput[i].value = "Hello";  
        break;
    }
}
```

Change "name" and "Hello" as needed. :)